# Are median London prices noticeable higher than the rest of the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, price, london

It is common knowledge that London prices are much higher than that of the rest of the UK. However, I have heard that this isn't strictly true; the prices of most typical purchases from food and drink, going to the cinema, through to buying a new TV are much the same as elsewhere. Often quoted average London prices are the result of there being more high-end establishments, skewing the mean, but not actually raising cost for the typical shopper. There are a few things which blatantly cost more than elsewhere, such as the the cost of housing, but the idea is that this is the exception not the rule.

Anecdotally I've found this to indeed be the case. I've been to London a number of times and haven't noticed paying more in restaurants, pubs or supermarkets than elsewhere. As such I've assumed the above to be true and stated it as such to a friend at the weekend. However, it occurs to me that I may be entirely wrong in this as I only have evidence which is either anecdotal or that I've heard at some point from some forgotten source. I have tried to find some more concrete evidence one way or the other but haven't found much other that the previously mentioned "average" prices which do not note whether the average they refer to is the mean or the median price.

I am therefore wondering: are median London prices actually higher than that of the rest of the UK, or are there simply more high end establishments skewing the mean?

To help demonstrate my line of thinking, here are some examples. Would I pay more in London than the rest of the UK for: a weekly shop at a Sainsbury's? A pint of Peroni at an equal-quality pub? A steak at an equal-quality family restaurant? A movie ticket at the Vue cinema?

Comment: here's a quick comparison with Birmingham, the site will allow you to compare with a number of other UK cities: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=United+Kingdom&country2=United+Kingdom&city1=Birmingham&city2=London&tracking=getDispatchComparison

Comment: I've come across similar sites while reading around, but as with the others I can't see any indication of whether or not these values are median or mean, which is the primary reason for my question. That said, it is interesting that there is a 50p difference in "McMeal at McDonalds", as I'm not sure there is such a thing as an "upmarket McDonalds" to skew the mean.

Comment: this is why I didn't add it as an answer. I haven't been to a McDonald's in 20 years so wouldn't know about their fine dining restaurants or lack thereof

Comment: Not sure about London, though I'd assume it's the same, but in Silicon Valley housing is several times the rest of the country, but most other things are "only" more like 0-50% more.

Comment: "mid-quality pub".. Are you here referring to pubs of the same quality - or mid quality from low to high in the city you are in? Same-quality pubs I would suspect have similar prices - but mid-quality pubs may not - because the mid-quality in London may be the same as the high-quality pub somewhere else, hence the London mid-quality pub I would expect to be more expensive than a mid-quality pub in a small town.

Comment: @ssn Good point. I mean a pub of equal quality; a mid-quality pub across the UK rather than locally. I was trying to rule out comparing a cheap pub in a small town vs a high-end pub in London. The point you're making is essentially what I'm trying to figure out. I suspect that when some people say London is more expensive they're often comparing apples and oranges; a good quality London pub versus a lesser pub elsewhere. That London isn't inherently (that much) more expensive, there is just a broader range of quality available.

Comment: In my experience, a typical pub in Coventry will sell beer for £2-£3 per pint, while in London the same beer would be £3-£4 or more in what I would consider the same level of establishment.  I would be surprised if supermarkets were much different though.

Comment: I found the raw data at https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/datasets/consumerpriceindicescpiandretailpricesindexrpiitemindicesandpricequotes so will process it when I get chance. There are 127000 ish data points so don't expect me to be quick!

Comment: Pubs *no more expensive in London?* Are you mad? Unless it's Wetherspoons, I cannot possibly envisage how you could perceive this to be the case. The last time I paid under £5 for a pint of anything in London was over a decade ago.

Comment: The last time I bought a pint in south London it cost a bit over £4, which is approximately what I would pay in a decent pub in Edinburgh. The question was originally prompted by a Londoner being surprised at paying "London prices" in Edinburgh. I'm aware there are places that charge considerably more than that in London (and elsewhere in the country) but that wasn't my question. Whether the price of a pint would vary between a Wetherspoons in Manchester or London is more what I'm looking for; though not perfect given 'spoons are probably below average quality.

Comment: It occurred to me that cinema prices are easy to check online. Comparing Dundee to London on the Odeon website comes out at £7.25 and £8.75 respectively. That's roughly a 21% markup which adds to the other evidence provided by others that my assertion was incorrect. Thanks folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having shopped in Sainsbury's in London and outside London within the same week, I can assure you that a full size Sainsbury's store in London charges more for the same goods than one outside, and that their "Local" stores charge more again. And that their prices everywhere increased shortly after the Brixit decision.

Comment: I'd think everything would be driven by property prices.  If Sainsbury's wants to open a store in London, the land and/or building space will cost much more than it would in say Market Blandings, and workers probably have to be paid more to cover the cost of their housing.  So Sainsbury's either has to raise prices in its London store to cover the increased cost, or let the rest of the country subsidize an unprofitable London store.

Comment: I've given this the green tick, thank you :) I was hoping for something more concrete than this, but I think it is enough to confirm that my line of thinking was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

In short, Yes. Some things very little (groceries etc) others a lot- you can draw a map of (pint of) beer prices across the country (which is a proxy for many other things). Cinema prices also are higher.